# TypeError: Cannot read property of 'service' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, arraylist, filter

So I have this modal that opens and shows the data from an arraylist after the button pertaining to that specific data is clicked. Well when I click the button the code works, but after a while, I get this Error TypeError: Cannot read property of `service` of undefined. As you can see that I am using the `.filter()` and `.map()` to get the data as well.

The error is being thrown at the `<Modal.Header>` line.

```
    let filelist = [
  {"id": 1, "service": 'InHome Services', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' +
  ' Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys'},
  {"id": 2, "service": 'Consumer Direct', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys '
+    
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys '},

  {"id": 3, "service": 'Private Duty Service', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' +
  
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys '},

  {"id": 4, "service": 'Home-make Chore', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' +
  
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys'},
  {"id": 5, "service": 'Nursing Care Service', "description":'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +
  
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' },
  { "id": 6, "service": 'Respite Care Service', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +
  
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys '},

  {"id": 7, "service": 'ASL Care Service', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +
  
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys '},

  {"id": 8, "service": 'Advance Care', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys'
+
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industryse' +
  
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys '},

  {"id": 9, "service": 'Healthy Children', "description": 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys' + 

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +
  
  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys ' +

  'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys '}
];

export default function Services() {
  
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState();
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();

  const handleClose = () => setShowModal(false);
  const handleCancel = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
    setSelectedFile(null);
  };
  const handleDelete = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
    //delete
    alert(`${selectedFile} has been deleted`);
    setSelectedFile(null);
  };
  return(
    <div className="App" style={{ marginTop: "222px" }}>
      {fileList.map(file => (
          <div>
            <Button
              style={{ margin: "2px" }}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedFile(file);
                setShowModal(true);
              }}
              key ={file.id} 
            >
              
              {file.service}
            </Button>
          </div>
      ))}
          <div>
                <div>
                <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                {fileList.filter(file => file.service === selectedFile.service).map(fileFiltered => (
                  <Modal.Title key = {fileFiltered.id} >
                    {fileFiltered.service}?
                  </Modal.Title>
                ))}
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>

              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCancel}>
                  Close
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleDelete}>
                  Yes
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

I think the issue is that you are storing an object in your `selectedFile` state and sometimes it's undefined or `null` and thus the `file.service === selectedFile.service` can potentially throw an error since you can't access the `service` property of `selectedFile` if it isn't an object.

## Solution

Store the `service` property in state instead.

```
{fileList.map((file) => (
  <div>
    <Button
      style={{ margin: "2px" }}
      onClick={() => {
        setSelectedFile(file.service); // <-- store service
        setShowModal(true);
      }}
      key={file.id}
    >
      {file.service}
    </Button>
  </div>
))}
<div>
  <div>
    <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        {fileList
          .filter((file) => file.service === service) // <-- check service
          .map((fileFiltered) => (
            <Modal.Title key={fileFiltered.id}>
              {fileFiltered.service}?
            </Modal.Title>
          ))}
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body></Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleCancel}>
          Close
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleDelete}>
          Yes
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Edit

I've created a running codesandbox with your shared code snippet and my solution applied.

[image: Edit typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-service-of-undefined]

Comment: I tried that method before, it still gave me the same error, and if I wanted to use the description in the modal body of my modal it would throw that error as well.

Comment: @Fwest Well, can you clarify which `service` access is throwing the error? What's in the modal body? Can you share what your `fileList` state is? It's likely either a null entry in the `fileList` state or the issue I pointed out above, or both, as these are the two places accessing that property. Can you provide a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: Sure, I went ahead and edited my question so you can see the entire component. The error is being thrown at line 117:52 inside the .filter and .map at the Modal header here: <Modal.Header closeButton>
                {fileList
                .filter((file) => file.service === service)
                .map(fileFiltered => (
                  <Modal.Title key = {fileFiltered.id} >
                    {fileFiltered.service}?
                  </Modal.Title>
                ))}
              </Modal.Header>

Comment: I dont understand why it is throwing this error because the app will run with the values inside the modal, but it would then crash after I have clicked the last button. Sometimes the ones before the last button

Comment: @Fwest I've created a running codesandbox with your shared code snippet and my solution applied. I am unable to reproduce the issue. You do import the data as `filelist` but reference it in your code as `fileList`, but I suspect this was more a copy/paste/typo when you updated your question.

Comment: Yeah, I copied the filelist from an old question I posted because I used Lorem Ipsum and didn't want to include the actual data that was going in the app, but I have updated that to fileList since then.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like modal component is rendering after you set `selectedFile` as `null`.
Try to add conditional rendering for your modal component, so it should not render if `selectedFile` does not exist

```
{selectedFile && (<Modal>...</Modal>)}
```